# How does increment operator work with arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, operators, increment

Here's code that confuses me:

```
var array = new int[5];
array[0] = 1;
array[0]++;
Console.WriteLine(array[0]);  //'2' is printed
```

I don't understand why array's item got incremented. From my understanding, the following should happend:

> 1st line: I create an array with a capacity for 5 ints.
>
> 2nd line: I put '1' into 0 index of this array
>
> **3rd line: I retrieve item from index 0 and increment it by 1**
>
> 4th line: I print the item at index 0

The 3rd line is the key here. I don't understand how number '2' got written into the array. I'm just reading the item and incrementing it.

Comment: `I don't understand how number '2' got written into the array.` What result did you **expect**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array[0]++;` is (roughly) equivalent to `array[0] += 1;`

so the value is written back to the aray location.

It is a side effect and there is a sequence issue to be aware of:

```
int y = array[0]++;       // now y == 1 and array[0] == 2

int y = (array[0] += 1);  // now y == 2 and array[0] == 2
```

Comment: The `array[0] += 1;` part made it clear for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In C#, increment and decrement operators operate on:

- Variables
- Property access
- Indexer access (your case)

The generated code also knows where to store the value back into.

If the operator only incremented a value, even `myVariable++` would do nothing.

See [Arithmetic Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here how it works:

```
array[0]++;
```

First, "array[0]" is evaluated.

Second, the increment is done on the value keeped by "array[0]".

For example, if you write:

```
if (array[0]++ == 2) DoSomething();
```

First, the condition (array[0] == 2) is evaluated.

Second, the array[0] is incremented.

Third, the next instruction is executed.

But if you write:

```
if (++array[0] == 2) DoSomething();
```

First, the array[0] is incremented.

Second, the condition (array[0] == 2) is evaluated.

Third, the next instruction is executed.

If you write only an increment in one instruction:

```
++x;
```

Or

```
x++;
```

It does the same thing.